# Readable to Buffer function doesn't work because Readable doesn't emit `end` event

Tags: node.js, typescript, stream, buffer, fetch-api

So I have a typical `streamToBuffer` function:

```js
const streamToBuffer = async (stream: NodeJS.ReadableStream): Promise<Buffer> => {
  const chunks: Buffer[] = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('data', (chunk: WithImplicitCoercion<ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer>) =>
      chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)),
    );
    stream.on('error', reject);
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
  });
};
```

It's, as far as I know, the usual way of transforming streams into buffers in NodeJS.

Well, there are some instances where the `end` event doesn't happen. Neither does `error` or `close`. Just `data` event is fired and the promise then never gets resolved/rejected.

How could that be possible?

I think the only situations when this happens are when retrieving a file using the `node-fetch` library.

```js
const getBinary = async (id: string) => {
  return await fetch(`an internal URL with the id`, {
    method: 'GET',
  })
    .then(async (response) => {
      switch (response.status) {
        case 200:
          return new Readable().wrap(response.body!); // <-- This Readable
        case 404:
          throw new NotFound(await response.json());
        default:
          throw new BadGateway(await response.json());
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new InternalServerError(err);
    });
};
```

I'm not 100% sure if the issue only happens with a stream obtained like this. But to the best of my ability it appears it is the case. Mind you, not every time. Only for some `id` values, so certain binaries.

Some extra information: if I navigate with my browser or use curl with any of the problematic URLs everything works fine. I get the file with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the doc for `readable.wrap()` it is not meant for the type of stream in `response.body`.  `fetch()` returns a WebStream, not the old style nodejs stream that `.wrap()` is meant to be used with.

In recent versions of nodejs, you can use `Readable.fromWebStream(webStream)` to convert from a webStream to a nodejs Readable stream.  Nodejs [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options).

```
return Readable.fromWeb(response.body);
```

Here's an example: https://css-tricks.com/web-streams-everywhere-and-fetch-for-node-js/#aa-node-streams-interoperability.

In older versions of nodejs, you can use an http request library like `got` or `axios` that directly supports getting a response as a nodejs readstream.

```
const readStream = got.stream(url);
```

Comment: I see that the function was added in NodeJS v17.0.0. I am unfortunately forced to use v16.6.0. What would be the alternative for my version?

Comment: @BlueSialia - Use a third party library such as `got()` or `node-fetch()` instead of `fetch()` that supports nodejs streams directly.  The browser-designed `fetch()` supports a webStream only.

Comment: I specifically state in the post that I use the `node-fetch()` library.

Comment: @BlueSialia -  OK, then use `got()` or `axios()` that create node-specific streams.  I thought node-fetch did too, but you are saying apparently not.

Comment: @BlueSialia - For example,  `const readStream = got.stream(url);`.